# How to determine QR code scanning device?

Tags: .net, qr-code

Is there a way to uniquely determine the device that is scanning a QR code? I was hoping that some metadata or something is/could be sent in the process.

I'm building a web app and creating a QR Code for users from which I would like to do two things:

1. If a specific device (QR Code scanning hardware at the desk of the office) scans it, I'd like to increase number of logins by 1 for that user.
2. If any other device (user mobile phone) scans it, show details for that user.

I'm using QRCoder (https://github.com/codebude/QRCoder/) to generate QR code.

Comment: Most scanners just function as keyboards. You probably need low level keyboard access, which is impossible in a webapp